# Implement a real-time notification system for an HTML5 Django web app

Tags: javascript, django, html, angularjs, notifications

I'm currently working on a HTML5 web-app served by Django/apache.

The app's goal is to monitor a couple of devices : all the client-side logic is written with Angular and all the data comes from JSON-based REST-like calls made to the backend (pretty common stuff I assume).

This is working rather well, so far. Now I'd like to implement a notification system: *something that would react to external events and would notify all the running web-app instances that something needs to be refreshed on the page*. I really don't want all instances to just poll the server because that seems sub-optimal. Especially on mobile devices where this would likely drain the battery quickly.

I have very little experience with this kind of stuff (I'm more of a backend developer, so this is all pretty new to me). I was first thinking of making a long-lived HTTP request from the Javascript side to the server: this request would only give a result after either a timeout period (in which case the client would have to retry and wait again, right away) or after something changed (it would then reply with some information about models that needs to be refreshed).

This seems like it could work in theory, but I figured I'd rather ask first because it seems so common, I would be surprised if no framework existed for this kind of task.

#### So my question is: is there a de-facto standard/technology to use in such cases and/or what would you recommend to implement it ?

The server is running in a VM over which I have a **total control**: meaning I can install whatever software I need to implement that. I'd like to avoid having to use several network ports as much as possible but if it makes things really easier, then it's fine.

Comment: Take a look into websockets, they can be used for real-time events without having to use polling. As for frameworks, I haven't seen any nice ones that integrate with django. JS devs seem to only care about NodeJS these days.

Answer (score 4):

Real-time updation can be done in (at least) two approaches: (1) continuous polling, (2) Websocket Protocol

My personal favourite is Websocket Protocol (but older browsers don't support it, so may be, you'll need a fallback on continuous or long polling). Django (1.9) does not support WebSocket protocol as of now. So your Django project will need a sidekick which can help implementing Websocket protocol. Common choices are [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) and NodeJS. I am showing Tornado example below:

Create an auxiliary tornado project (You might have to host it on a different server in production environment). There you can have a `WebSocketHandler` as shown below:

```
import tornado.websocket

# suppose URL for this handler is localhost:8888/my_handler/
class MyWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    waiters = set()

    def open(self):
        MyWebSocketHandler.waiters.add(self)

    def on_close(self):
        MyWebSocketHandler.waiters.remove(self)

    def on_message(self, message):
        MyWebSocketHandler.send_updates(message)

    @classmethod
    def send_updates(cls, stuff_django_project_sends):
        for waiter in cls.waiters:
            waiter.write_message(stuff_django_project_sends)
```

In your HTML5 app, you will have something like this (This is plain JavaScript, I don't know it's AngularJS equivalent):

```
var url = "ws://localhost:8888/my_handler/";
socket = new WebSocket(url);  // establish connection with WebSocketHandler to listen to updates
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    var stuff_django_project_sent = JSON.parse(event.data));
    // do something with this stuff now
}
```

Now in your Django Project too, you'll establish connection to this WebSocketHandler. But there you will send updates to Tornado project, which will then, send updates to HTML5 app.

First you'll have to install [websocket-client](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) package in django. Then you'll do something like:

```
from websocket import create_connection
import json

url = "ws://localhost:8888/my_handler/"
web_socket = create_connection(url)
web_socket.send(json.dumps({'stuff': 'to send'}))
```