# How to implement websocket for push message using django-rest-framework as backend and angular2 as frontend?

Tags: django, angular, rest, websocket, django-rest-framework

- I want to implement `websocket` to send push notification to client.
- I am using `django-rest framework` as backend and `angular2` as frontend.
- I know that django support `HTTP` protocol only. And I am unable to get
  any such links,blogs or resource which helps me to achieve websocket
  completely.
- Currently I am using polling from frontend.
- There are some third party apps which I found and may be useful for
  implementing push message. They are...

  [pywebsocket](https://github.com/google/pywebsocket)

  [tornado](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado)

  [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)
- I don't think showing some code is significant here because i have no
  code relevent to implementation of  websocket.
- So can you people suggest me the best way to implement this thing.Any
  link,any blog or any code which may help.

Comment: Take a look at django-websockets https://django-websocket-redis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ They act a little differently to normal HTTP connections

Comment: Hi, go with django channels as they was adopted as django project:  https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2016/sep/09/channels-adopted-official-django-project/

You can find pretty good tutorials how to do it, for example: https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to deploy a separate `Tornado` app which communicates with Front-end using `WebSocket`. Then, whenever the Django Back-end wants to send a push notification to the Front-end, it asks the `Tornado` app and `Tornado` app delivers the push notification to Front-end.

I have described the process in slightly more detail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484929/implement-a-real-time-notification-system-for-an-html5-django-web-app/37523431#37523431) answer of mine. You might want to have a look.